# Validate AutoMapper configuration at startup

Tags: c#, automapper, autofac, asp.net-core-2.1

We are using `Automapper` to map from the `Domain` object to `Repository` object and visa-versa. There is a deep nesting of child properties within a single domain. The `Repository` layer and Automapper have been added retrospectively. As a result, we have to create a Mapping `Profile` for several classes do the mapping.

For example:

### A sample `Domain` Class

```
public class MyDomain 
{
   public ChildDomain1 ChildDomain1  {get; set; }

   public IList<ChildDomain2> ChildDomain2  {get; set; }

   public ChildDomain3 ChildDomain3  {get; set; }

.

.

.

}
```

### A sample `Repository` Class

```
public class MyRepository
{
   public ChildRepository1 ChildRepository1  {get; set; }

   public IList<ChildRepository2> ChildRepository2  {get; set; }

   public ChildRepository3 ChildRepository3  {get; set; }

.

.

.

}
```

### Automapper `Profile` Mapping

```
public class MapProfile : Profile
{
    public MapProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<MyDomain, MyRepository>()
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<ChildDomain1, ChildRepository1>()
            .ReverseMap();

        .   

        .

        .
   }
}
```

### AutofacModel to register `Domain`/ `Repository` `Profile`

```
public class DocumentMapperAutofacModule : Module
{
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MapProfile).Assembly)
                .Where(t => typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsPublic)
                .As<Profile>();

            builder.Register(c => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {

                foreach (var profile in c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>())
                {
                    cfg.AddProfile(profile);
                }
            })).AsSelf().SingleInstance();

            builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>()
                    .CreateMapper(c.Resolve))
                .As<IMapper>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }
 }
```

### Problem Statement

Currently, we get below Automapper exception, when a missing mapping is encountered while doing a map at the run time.

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration
>   or unsupported mapping.

Our problem is that it is too late already.

### Question

- How do we ensure that a mapping exists for every child property in `Domain`/ `Repository` at the Application Start? Is there any easy way/ custom code to throw an exception at Application Start when mapping is missing?
- Or, is the unit/ integration tests to validate the mapping an only way around?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html

Comment: Hi @LucianBargaoanu this was great. Thanks for your help. I wonder how I missed that. If you add this to answer, I can accept the answer. Or else, I can add the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue using `AssertConfigurationIsValid` following the advice from @Lucian Bargaoanu in the comment, I added a Unit Test (using `xunit`in this case) to `Assert` the mapping as follows:

```
public class ValidateMappingTests
{
        [Fact]
        public void ItShouldAssertTheMappingSuccessfully()
        {
            var mapping = new MapperConfiguration(_ => _.AddProfiles(
                typeof(MapProfile).Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract && myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Profile)))
                .Select(type => (Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(type))));

            mapping.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
}
```

**Update**

I realized that the above code did not validate the `ReverseMap`. This apparently is expected behavior. [Here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2327#) are the details.

Quoting Jimmy Bogard (the author):

> Ah, this is the expected behavior. ReverseMap is different, it assumes you're literally flattening and un-flattening. For un-flattening, you'd want to assert that the source side is all mapped, not the destination. Reverse map doesn't assume you want to assert anything, since you've already validated the Source -> Destination mapping.
>
> In short, ReverseMap is now "special" and not merely a short cut for two CreateMap calls.

To get around this I updated my test method as below:

```
[Fact]
 public void ItShouldAssertTheMappingSuccessfully()
 {
     var mapping = new MapperConfiguration(_ => _.AddProfiles(
         typeof(MapProfile).Assembly.GetTypes()
             .Where(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract && myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Profile)))
             .Select(type => (Profile) Activator.CreateInstance(type))));

   // Added below line as per comment from GitHub to assert the ReverseMap
     foreach (var map in mapping
                         .GetAllTypeMaps()
                         .Where(_ => _== MemberList.None))
         map.ConfiguredMemberList = MemberList.Destination;

     mapping.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at `AssertConfigurationIsValid` in the [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html).

> To test our configuration, we simply create a unit test that sets up the configuration and executes the AssertConfigurationIsValid method:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
  cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>());

configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Examples of a profiles setup with automapper:

```
public class VendorProfile : Profile
  {
    public VendorProfile()
    {
      CreateMap<Vendor, VendorV1>();

      CreateMap<VendorV1, Vendor>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.LastUpdated, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
  }

public class MessageProfile : Profile
  {
    public MessageProfile()
    {
      CreateMap<Message, MessageV1>();

      CreateMap<MessageV1, Message>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.LastUpdated, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
  }
```

An example test using AssertConfigurationIsValid from automapper's docs:

```
public class ProfilesTest
  {
    [Fact]
    public void ProfilesMappingSuccessfully()
    {
      var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
      {
        cfg.AddProfile(new VendorProfile());
        cfg.AddProfile(new MessageProfile());
      });

      config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
  }
```

Comment: @DEX7RA i updated the answer with a quote from the obvious automapper docs source

Comment: Alright seems to be bettter. I format your link in the proper way. Thanks for updating!